# Do i need to unescape the Encrypted String after using mysql_real_escape_string on it?

Tags: php, .net, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

In PHP, i have a `action.php` page, i have a string which is stored into a variable

```
$myString = "Foo Bar";
```

I'm encrypting this string using AES256 with the following function :

```
function aes256Encrypt($key, $data) {

if(32 !== strlen($key)) $key = hash('SHA256', $key, true);

$padding = 16 - (strlen($data) % 16);

$data .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);

return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,    str_repeat("\0", 16));

}
```

And before inserting data to MySQL database, I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string()` to the encrypted string before inserting it to DB

In my knowledge, the `mysql_real_escape_string()` function adds `\` before the charachters that need to be escaped !

In the other hand, i need to get the data back from MySQL and decrypt it using this function :

```
  function aes256Decrypt($key, $data) {

  if(32 !== strlen($key)) $key = hash('SHA256', $key, true);

  $data = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,   str_repeat("\0", 16));

  $padding = ord($data[strlen($data) - 1]);

  return substr($data, 0, -$padding);

  }
```

Everything is OK, when i decrypt the string that i get from db, i get the correct string back, but I get really confused on how could this work correctly without un-escaping the string back after getting it from DB ?

Comment: Notice: `mysql()*`is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should really switch from using `mysql_*` to either PDO or mysqli and use properly parameterized statements.  Then, you avoid calls to `mysql_real_escape_string` altogether.

The escaping concept is very broad in programming, and it applies here.  Say you want to store someone's name to the DB: `Coryn O'Driscoll`.  This is not even malicious, but this query will fail:

```
INSERT INTO Names VALUES ('Coryn O'Driscoll')
```

You have an unclosed string.

`mysql_real_escape_string` converts this to `('Coryn O\'Driscoll'`).  The `\'` signals to mysql that the apostrophe is not a part of the syntax of the query but actuall part of the scalar value to insert.  It is actually inserted as `Coryn O'Driscoll`.  This is why you don't have to remove any backslashes from it when you select it again.